# Flexible projectile system?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Projectiles need to accommodate timed, homing, linear, and arced behaviours and have single, cone, and splash effects on hit. What is a good pattern to accommodate these different behaviours that require different parameters?

I want a system where I can call something like `ProjectileManager.Fire (*Projectile Parameters*)` from anywhere and have a projectile get fired. How would parameters like `timeToDetonate`, `coneAngle`, and `aoeRadius` be handled in a user-friendly way?

Comment: What exactly troubles you in this system?

Comment: Couldn't you just have a base Projectile class that you inherit from for the specific projectiles you speak about? Then make the parameter for the fire method take in a Projectile, instantiation position and direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no problem. Just declare a multitude of Fire functions each of which calls respective projectile class constructor. More code on the inside, but simplest interface on the outside (easy to use):

```
ProjectileManager.FireA(param1, param2);
ProjectileManager.FireB(param1, param2_typeA, param3);
ProjectileManager.FireC(param1, param2_typeB, param3);
ProjectileManager.FireD(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5);
```

Alternatively, use constructors on the outside (less code inside):

```
ProjectileManager.Fire(TProjectileA.Create(param1, param2));
ProjectileManager.Fire(TProjectileB.Create(param1, param2_typeA, param3));
ProjectileManager.Fire(TProjectileC.Create(param1, param2_typeB, param3));
ProjectileManager.Fire(TProjectileD.Create(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5));
```